# Something different about partial factorization with wolfram alpha

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

I was factorizing $$f(x) = \frac{4x^2+7x+2}{4x^3+4x^2+2x}$$
I approached this like below
$$f(x) = \frac{a}{2x} + \frac{bx+c}{2x^2+2x+1}$$
and got a = 2, b = 0, c = $\frac{3}{2}$. So, f(x) becomes

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{3}{2x^2+2x+1}$$ (multiplied 2 to c because I reduced $\frac{2}{2x}$)

However, when I run this in wolfram alpha I get something like below,
[Wolfram screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsarD.png)
I can't find an explanation for the denominators splitting into $2x$ and $ 2(2x^2+2x+1)$ where did the 2 in the 2nd denominator come from?

Comment: It seems that an $x$ is missing in the first expression.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A numerical factor in the left-hand denominator can appear on the right-hand side in a number of ways.

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{4x^2+7x+2}{x(2x^2+2x+1)} 
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{a}{x} + \frac{bx+c}{2x^2+2x+1} \right)  \\
&= \frac{a}{2x} + \frac{bx+c}{2(2x^2+2x+1)}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{4x^2+7x+2}{x(2x^2+2x+1)} 
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{a}{x} + \frac{bx+c}{2x^2+2x+1} \right)  \\
&= \frac{a/2}{x} + \frac{(b/2)x+(c/2)}{2x^2+2x+1}  \text{,}  
\end{align*}
or even a combination such as in your version
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{4x^2+7x+2}{x(2x^2+2x+1)} 
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{a}{x} + \frac{bx+c}{2x^2+2x+1} \right)  \\
&= \frac{a}{2x} + \frac{(b/2)x+(c/2)}{2x^2+2x+1}
\text{.}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The $\,2\,$ in the denominator is a numerical common factor and should be removed before separating into partial fractions. In other words, the steps should be

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{4x^2+7x+2}{4x^3+4x^2+2x} &= \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{4x^2+7x+2}{2x^3+2x^2+x}\right]\\[1ex]
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{a}{x} + \frac{bx+c}{2x^2+2x+1}\right]\\[1ex]
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{2}{x} + \frac{3}{2x^2+2x+1}\right]\\[1ex]
&= \frac{1}{x} + \frac{3}{2(2x^2+2x+1)}\\[1ex]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Is this the same explanation for the wrong answers when I spit the denominators to $x$ and $4x^2+4x+2$ or $2x$ and $2x^2+2x+1$?

Comment: Well, the answer you gave is not in fact wrong, I was just saying that it's much more convenient to remove numerical common factors from the partial fractions calculation. You got $\,c=\frac{3}{2}\,$, which would have given $$\frac{\frac{3}{2}}{(2x^2+2x+1)} = \frac{3}{2(2x^2+2x+1)}$$ The only mistake seems to have been where you said "(multiplied 2 to c because I reduced $\frac{2}{2x}$)", I'm not really sure what you mean there.